# Снова о причастии

Tags: причастия

Влияет ли значение исходного глагола на часть речи?

> Сегодня было такое **палящее** солнце!

С одной стороны, это ***очень жаркое*** солнце.
С другой стороны, это солнце, ***которое палит***. Недавно вы говорили, что для перехода в прилагательное значение должно поменяться на переносное. Но я сомневаюсь, что в данном случае оно переносное (пометы "перен." нет)?

```
Обдавать жаром, зноем (о солнечных лучах); жечь, печь. **Солнце палит**. **Зной, жар, жара палит**. **День, полдень палит**. ☐ безл. Этим летом сильно палило. Пошёл солнцем палимый кто-л. (разг.; об обманутом в своих ожиданиях).
```

Comment: на -щее бывают прилагательные?

Comment: @Буратино, бывает.

Comment: https://lexicography.online/explanatory/mas/п/палящий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратим внимание на пометку в словаре: ***Палящий*** (см.).  Смотрим соответствующую статью.

**ПАЛЯЩИЙ**, -ая, -ее. 1. к Палить (1.П.). 2. **Очень жаркий, обжигающий.** П-ие лучи солнца. П. зной. П. день. П. пар.

**Это уже прилагательное или причастие?** (во втором значении словарной статьи).   Вероятно, надо спросить у составителей словаря. Но я думаю так: Причастие без зависимых слов, да еще образованное от глагола со вторичным значением в значительной степени проявляет **качественное** значение: палящий – это очень жаркий. Это **признак ПЕРЕХОДА** причастия в прилагательное.

Но, возможно, это всего лишь **причастие**, которое  употреблено в значении **прилагательного?** Очень может быть. Например: [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/палящий](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9). **Делайте выводы сами.**

**P.S.** Все сведения я беру из словарей или грамматических источников. Все желающие могут их **проверить** и сделать **собственные выводы.**

**ЧТО МОЖНО УВИДЕТЬ В СЛОВАРЕ?**

Речь идет о толковом словаре Кузнецова.

Нет пометки "переносное"? Но зато есть **особая статья** для слова "палящий". Но там не указано, что это **прилагательное**? А это нигде не указывается, стоит только посмотреть значение любого прилагательного.  А вот для причастия **особой статьи не бывает**, потому что это **особая форма глагола**.

Но это у Кузнецова не указывается, а у Ефремовой указывается, что это **прилагательное**. [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/208147/Палящий](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/208147/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Значит, лингвисты тоже **сомневаются?**

И из этого тоже надо сделать **собственные выводы.** Это нужно для разбора в школе? Там всё очень условно (впрочем, условности везде хватает. Тогда нужно знать, **как нужно** разбирать (тематика **общественного договора**).

[О лексических метафорах и  просто метафорах](https://vuzlit.com/432602/suschnost_metafory_funktsii#:%7E:text=1.%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C,%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

Метафорический перенос названия происходит также и при развитии у слова на базе основного, номинативного значения производного значения (спинка стула, ручка двери). Однако в этих, так называемых **языковых метафорах** образ отсутствует, чем они принципиально отличаются от поэтических.

**Лексическая метафора**, или стертая, в которой прямое значение полностью отсутствует; дождь идет, время бежит, стрелка часов, дверная ручка.

[Еще статья по теме](https://lit.wikireading.ru/hONcIVunGW)

Из словаря Кузнецова: **РУЧКА**, ж.  2. Часть предмета, за которую его держат или берут рукой. Дверная р.

Как мы видим, пометки "перен." нет. А ***море пшеницы***? Значение явно переносное, но и у этого значения нет пометки "перен." Ну тогда хотя  бы так: От любви душа ***расцвела!***. Увы, это значение тоже не имеет пометки. И возникает вопрос: где вообще **можно увидеть "перен"?**

Comment: Ещё в [Викисловаре](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/палящий) указано, что прилагательное. Причём значение "очень жаркий, обжигающий" стоит на первом месте, а на втором причастие от "палить".

Comment: Грамота. ру. как-то писала о переносном и прямом значении в словарях. Если найду ссылку, добавлю.

Comment: @sharon, http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&start=15  Вопрос № 296676

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Ну и как вам объяснение, туманное оно какое-то, точности не хватает... У Ожегова:  перен. Неопытный по молодости (молодо-зелено).  Но это тоже объяснение в словосочетании, а не напрямую. К тому же у Кузнецова уже появилось НОВОЕ значение: 6. Очень юный; неопытный по молодости. А пометка перен. исчезла... А почему?  Или вот: при таком понимании, в возможно другое прочтение... А ПРАВИЛЬНО-ТО как?

Comment: @sharon может, Кузнецов считает, что у слова "зеленый"метафорическое  значение стерлось, оно стало производным. Я бы не стал убирать помет. перен. В остальном согласен с Грамотой.

Comment: Кстати, мне уведомление не пришло. Поэтому только сейчас ответил.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Причастие или прилагательное — вот вечный вопрос!**

Его приходится решать и в правописании, и при грамматическом разборе. Причастие может утратить значение действия, приобрести качественный признак и перейти в прилагательное. Адъективация бывает полной или временной, все признаки перехода давно известны и перечислены в учебных пособиях (см. приложение).

**Переносное значение** — главная идея перехода,  да вот только с этим переносным значением тоже не все ясно (см. ответ Грамоты. ру).  Сомневаются не только пользователи,  но и лингвисты тоже…

**2.  Может быть, нужна новая идея?**

Возможно, что и так. Поэтому поиски в этом направлении нужно приветствовать. Вот только идея эта должна быть **понятной и ясно обозначенной**, а иначе пользователь спросит: а зачем мне всё это нужно, как я могу применить все сказанное при выборе формы письма. А еще скажет: я ничего не понял, мне нужны определения, точные формулировки. Он это непременно скажет…

Более того, идея должна быть обозначена именно **на «грамматическом языке»,** а не дана в качестве описания. К примеру, идея переноса расписана очень подробно, но здесь, возможно, не хватает именно новой семантики, нового подхода.

**3. Какие неточности можно отметить при ответе?**

Прежде всего, нужно точно следовать **толковому словарю.**

**ПАЛИТЬ,** нсв. 1. (св. опалить). кого. Держа над огнём, обжигать, удалять волосяной покров, пух и т.п. П. гуся. П. свинью. П. шкуру. 5. Обдавать жаром, зноем (**о солнечных лучах**); жечь, печь. **Солнце палит**. Зной, жар, жара палит. **Паление**, -я; ср. (1 зн.). **Палящий** (см.).

**ПАЛЯЩИЙ**, 1. к Палить (**1.П.**). 2. Очень жаркий, обжигающий. П-ие лучи солнца. П. зной. П. день. П. пар.

**Палить?** Значение  (5) глагола "палить"  явно переносное по отношению к прямому значению (1), хотя такой пометки перен. нет (с этими пометками одни проблемы!).

**Палящий?**  Форма «палящий» (жаркий) относится только к значению глагола (5)  Палящее (жгучее)  солнце.

**Наречие «паляще»?**  Оно образовано от «палящий» (предположительно прилагательного). Можно заметить, что при образовании наречий с суффиксом  ЮЩ приходится учитывать **фонетику,** а то неблагозвучно.

*Я узнал, чьи эти деньги, а это уже немало, ― спокойно сказал я, морщась от **паляще** острой горчицы. Дни **паляще-знойные**. Дождя нет. Оно темно и светисто, **паляще** и морозно, животворно и убийственно.*  Кстати, здесь дефисная форма — это два однородных прилагательных (палящий и знойный). А "паляще" в последнем примере весьма похоже на краткое прилагательное.

**Паление?** Существительное относится к значению (1) для глагола. Паление гуся, да?

**Предикат?**  Но у нас есть предложения без предиката (назывные и эллиптические): *Палящее солнце! Сегодня такое палящее солнце!* Да и в современном синтаксисе вроде бы уже не считается, что все предложения строятся по схеме с предикатом. И многое зависит от структуры предложения, от порядка слов.

**Вывод.** Идея может быть полезной и нужной, но на пути к ее реализации очень много подводных камней. Поэтому все должно быть тщательно продумано))

**4. О «бредовых»  стихах**

Говорят, что бред бывает вполне совместим с гениальностью))  Мне стихи понравились, **это классно!**  *Было лето, или утро, или тучи, или день, Или ветер, или вечер, или дождик, или тень. Было рано, или осень, или месяц, или пыль, То ли завтра, то ли в полдень мне приснилась эта быль…*

Нам уже скучно воспринимать мир последовательно, но хочется представить его **целостный образ.** И тогда мы перечисляем несовместимые предметы в виде однородного ряда…  А вот мультфильм нехорош, я бы его по-другому сняла: желательно **больше красок, больше эмоций**!  Кстати, поэтам и художникам эти стихи нравятся…

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Признаки адъективации причастий** (по учебнику для вузов Г.Ф. Рахимкуловой «Морфология современного русского языка»)

1. Утрата зависимых слов: жареный на масле картофель (прич.) — жареный картофель (прил.).
2. Употребление в переносном значении: извиняющаяся девушка (прич.) — извиняющая улыбка (прил.).
3. Вхождение в состав терминологического сочетания: пишущая машинка — это машинка, приспособленная для письма, а не та, которая пишет.
4. Утрата парного причастия: извиняющаяся девушка — извинившаяся девушка.
5. Способность образовывать степени сравнения, краткую форму, определительное наречие: дискуссия стала оживленнее, образованнейший человек, подробности потрясающи, подействовало ошеломляюще.

Answer (score 0):

Палящее теоретически может быть прилагательным, но мне кажется здесь фраза составлена слишком криво, чтобы палящее стало прилагательным.

А именно такое + палящее + солнце.

Солнце и должно быть палящим - это нормально, потому что это вполне себе функция солнца как источника излучения, огня - палить. Палящий огонь - это причастие + существительное. Палящее + солнце - это тоже причастие и существительное. Сегодня солнце палящее - уже достаточно. Такое - лишнее слово создающее тавтологию. Солнце не может быть такое или не такое палящее. Оно может палить меньше, но не само по себе.

Но давайте разберем, о чем собственно тут речь.

"Сегодня такое палящее солнце" - о чем собственно речь, где предикатив, если это прилагательное?

> Предикативные прилагательные - это прилагательные, которые встречаются после существительного. Предикативные прилагательные всегда следуют за связующим глаголом. Предикативные прилагательные также действуют как предметное дополнение. Например,
> Он печальный.
> Это яблоко красное.
> Моя мама выглядит усталой.

А где в предложении "сегодня такое палящее солнце" предикатив?

А его нет. Фраза бессмысленная, если это прилагательное.

А если предикатив такое, то тоже не лучше, потому что: а какое оно должно быть - солнце, если это горящее и следовательно палящее космическое тело? Оно и должно быть палящее, потому что оно горит, других солнц не бывает, это не условие солнца.

Также если поменять местами. Солнце палящее, это солнце палящее - не звучит совсем, значит не прилагательное. Солнце палит, солнце, палящее все вокруг, - такие да.

Не нужно путать с переносными значениями вроде "гулящий муж". Хотя "муж гулящий" - звучит как юмор, но тем не менее подвид мужа - "гулящий", хоть как-то. А солнце палящее - никак в подвид солц палящих не выделяется. Потому что к солнцу палящий имеет прямое отношение.

Гулящий - это не тот, который гуляет, а ведущий себя неверно. От наречия.

Тусклое солнце - почему прилагательное? Потому что от тускло.

А от какого наречия палящее? Как образовать наречие от слово палящее?

Да, и было - временной глагол, не выступает в роли предиката. Остается только "сегодня". Ну сегодня, само собой могло случится все, что угодно, и палящее могло стать прилагательным, но только сегодняшним.

Ладно, еще проще. Палящее - то, что палит, источник огня, жара. Наречие является результатом действия паления - опалено, опаленное может быть прилагательным. Но палящее не может быть прилагательным, так как то, что палит, не обладает свойством которое отдает. Либо есть еще слова палый - но смысл у него тоже обожженный, а не жгущий. У слова жгущий есть форма жгучий, обладающий жжением, но слова палючий нет. В общем я не могу найти подходы как от слова палящий образовать наречие или внятное прилагаетельное.

Вообще не всегда можно образовать прилагательные. Например, есть слово мечтать, вот оно не имеет весьма кривую множественную форму мечт, и есть понятие мечта, почему понятие, потому что это не что-то конкретное и не результат чего-то, но процесс мечтания. И прилагательное от него так же не образуется. Мечтный?

Comment: Солнце бывает ласковое, теплое, а бывает о-очень жаркое, палящее, в том числе немилосердно палящее. «1579 год. Белое немилосердно палящее солнце, пыль столбом по дорогам Казани. Пыль и пепел от недавнего пожара…»  Предикатив? Это очень сложный вопрос))  Но вот предложение: Сегодня весь день / было солнце. Смысл сказанного понятен, хотя определения вообще нет. И такой вопрос: в словаре Кузнецова указано 8 значений для слова «быть», вы какое выберете?

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/каким-бывает/солнце

Comment: @Sharon  согласен со всеми словосочетаниями, кроме "огонь горячий". Ласковое - от ласково, теплое - от тепло. А от какого наречия слово палящее - паляще? Но я там проглядел было, это да. Но все равно фраза "сегодня было такое палящее солнце" мне режет слух, сегодня палило солнце - так должна звучат фраза или сегодня было палящее солнце. Было - не является предикатом, было - это глагол времени, он выступает вспомогательным, в сочетании с предикатом. Было холодно

Comment: . А было солнце... это как в армянском мультике: Было лето, или утро, или тучи, или день,
Или ветер, или вечер, или дождик, или тень.
Было рано, или осень, или месяц, или пыль,
То ли завтра, то ли в полдень мне приснилась эта быль.
... То есть этот бредовый ряд с предикатом "было" можно было бы и дальше продолжать). Было солнце - это было солнечно.

Comment: А наречие паляще как-то не прижилось, всего 4 употребления: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjwqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGQoXChUKA3JlcRIOCgzQv9Cw0LvRj9GJ0LUwAQ==

Comment: То есть я хочу сказать, что прилагательные происходят от наречий или существительных являющихся понятиями, номинативами(переносными значениями слов), наречные существительные, а причастия - от глаголов, но нормальных, а не временных

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/919370 - Паление - действие от глагола палить, а не понятие "паление". Понятия паление нет или другого от слова палящий нет, наречия нет, с чего быть прилагательному? Если взять другое отглагольное понятие - каление, то там есть хотя бы белое каление, красное каление. А паление - какими характеристиками обладает, кроме непосредственного паления?

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии...  Я, возможно, немного позже запишу свое мнение в поле ответа.

Comment: @Sharon да вам спасибо, мне интересно обсудить. Насчет каления, я там добавил. Каление - это когда что-то раскаляют и закаляют, воздействие на вещь и придание неких свойств вещи. А палящее - это не характеристика солнца, причина солнца - огонь, горение.

Comment: @Sharon вот помните, я говорил про игру слов в английском языке. Вот пример того, как создается английский сленг. Слово Jeep  - на самом деле это акроним(произношение сокращения) от аббревиатуры GP - general purpose - общего назначения, которое на жаргоне военных значит машина не военного или особого, а в том числе и общего, возможно и гражданского, назначения. То есть тут прямо шифровки, то есть джип - это корпорация изначально военная, но которая стала производить в том числе и гражданский транспорт, придумав соответствующий "сленговый" бренд шифровку.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/jeep - GP, вот это чисто сленг, слово истинное значение которого зашифровано и перешифровано, чтобы никто не догадался, даже среди военных, а потом из него сделали еще и звучащий бренд.