# Спорный вопрос в лингвистике

Tags: причастия

Скажите, если была задача определить часть речи слова в словосочетании "**шокирующий** случай", будет ли корректным такой ответ ребенка:

> Это причастие, использованное в значении прилагательного.

Кроме того, он объяснил, почему так думает:

> Нет зависимого слова, можно сказать "крайне шокирующий случай", "более
> шокирующего случая (не было)", подбирается синоним - нестандартный.

К слову, изучалась тема разграничения причастий и адъективированных причастий.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150492/discussion-on-question-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К какой части речи относится то или иное слово следует определять по контексту (в словарях легко запутаться).
Случай – это уже состоявшееся событие,  происшествие, завершившийся эпизод, - история.  Причастие, в данном контексте, может находиться только в форме прошедшего времени: шокир**овавш**ий (своими последствиями) случай.
Поскольку «формирующегося (/ протекающего) в настоящее время случая» мы себе представить не можем, то решением задачи будет: шокирующий – это прилагательное.

Comment: Некорректное толкование.  Случай может произойти, а шокировать общественность он может как угодно долго. Для этого ему необязательно становиться прилагательным.  Вы только что узнали о нем, и он вас шокирует здесь и сейчас.

Comment: Выбрала ваш ответ, поскольку аргументы Sharon показались мне слишком "натянутыми".

Answer (score 2):

Слову «шокирующий» он-лайн словарь синонимов ставит в соответствие (помимо причастий: ошеломляющий, ужасающий, потрясающий...) еще и ряд прилагательных: скандальный, эпатажный, страшный, поразительный, тревожный.
https://sinonim.org/s/%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9#list-s
Однажды мне пришлось наблюдать редкостный, зримый, шокирующий переход от осени к зиме. [В. В. Ершов. Дневник (1992) // Летные дневники. 1984-2002 годы / Проза.ru]
Выполняя синтаксический разбор этого предложения, каждая нейросеть по своему определяет к какой часть речи относится слово «шокирующий». Одни нейросети называют его причастием, а другие (возможно потому, что их алгоритм рассматривает еще и знаки препинания в предложенной для анализа фразе) утверждают, что: дополнение в данном предложении состоит из нескольких прилагательных, перечисленных через запятую: “редкостный, зримый, шокирующий переход от осени к зиме”.
Учитывая, что (1) прилагательные и одиночные причастия не являются между собой однородными и, что (2) между неоднородными определениями запятая не ставится (...к реке спускался запущенный яблоневый сад...), мы должны признать, что авторская пунктуация в рассматриваемом примере относит слово «шокирующий» не к причастиям, а к прилагательным (например, в значении «поразительный»).

Отсюда вывод: возможность использования слова «шокирующий» в роли прилагательного ни в коем случае нельзя отрицать.

Comment: Все словарь пытаетесь обойти и сами себя в правоте убеждаете. У вас уже и авторская пунктуация в ход пошла, да только что она против словаря. Ученик должен уметь работать со словарем, это как абсолютная истина. Софистика в школе (могу доказать что угодно) нежелательна.  Но отчего не попробовать? Пусть школьник перепишет ваш ответ и отнесет учителю на проверку.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Как я понимаю, нужно ориентироваться на словари?
```

Да, именно **на словари,** там ответы на все вопросы.

1. Будем считать, что термин "причастие, использованное в значении прилагательного" устарел. Мы должны **однозначно** определиться: **причастие или прилагательное?**
2. Возьмем для сравнения слово ***палящий***, которое разбиралось на форуме  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474428/Снова-о-причастии](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474428/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8)

**ПАЛЯЩИЙ,** -ая, -ее. 1. к Палить (1.П.). 2. **Очень жаркий, обжигающий.** П-ие лучи солнца. П. зной. П. день. П.

Итак, это слово может быть **прилагательным.**

3. А теперь ищем слово ***"шокирующий"***. Но этого слова **нет в словаре,** есть только глагол "шокировать".

**ШОКИРОВАТЬ**, -рую, -руешь; нсв. [от франц. choquer]. кого (чем). Вызывать чувство неловкости, приводить кого-л. в смущение своим поведением, нарушением правил приличия, общепринятых норм поведения. Ш. гостей своими речами. Ш. окружающих своим поведением. Вас не шокирует мой наряд?

4. И делаем **вывод**: ***шокирующий*** – это причастие, то есть особая форма глагола.

Кстати, посмотрим на ряд **синонимов**: *шокирующий, ошеломляющий,  интригующий, потрясающий, ошарашивающий, волнующий, обескураживающий, будоражащий.*

Также: *эпатажный, скандальный.*

Видно, что подходящего **качественного** прилагательного-синонима для слова ***шокирующий*** нет.

Comment: Слово "шоковый" есть.

Comment: Относительное, не качественное прилагательное  ШОК, -а; м. [франц. choc - удар, толчок]. 1. Состояние общей подавленности организма (при травме головного мозга, введении чужеродного белка, психической травме и т.п.), выражающееся резким нарушением нервной регуляции жизненных процессов. Травматический ш. Находиться в состоянии глубокого шока. Выйти из шока. Смерть в результате шока. 2. Состояние крайней растерянности или подавленности. Нравственный ш. Нервный ш. От этого известия все были в шоке. Шоковый, -ая, -ое. Ш-ое состояние. Ш-ая эйфори

Answer (score 0):

```
Даже если очень хочется считать "шокирующий" прилагательным, 
так все равно делать нельзя.
```

Проверим слово по **признакам адъективации прилагательных.**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474335/Как-отличить-причастие-от-прилагательного](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474335/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

**Признаки адъективации причастий** (по учебнику для вузов Г.Ф. Рахимкуловой «Морфология современного русского языка»)

1. Утрата зависимых слов: жареный на масле картофель (прич.) — жареный картофель (прил.).
2. Употребление в переносном значении: извиняющаяся девушка (прич.) — извиняющая улыбка (прил.).  **Переносное значение не просматривается.**
3. Вхождение в состав терминологического сочетания: пишущая машинка — это машинка, приспособленная для письма, а не та, которая пишет.  **Это не терминологическое сочетание.**
4. Утрата парного причастия: извиняющаяся девушка — извинившаяся девушка. **Обе формы существуют.**
5. Способность образовывать степени сравнения, краткую форму, определительное наречие: дискуссия стала оживленнее, образованнейший человек, подробности потрясающи, подействовало ошеломляюще. **Нет краткой формы.**

Этих ответов достаточно, чтобы сделать вывод: **здесь нет адъективации причастия.**

О чем свидетельствуют **и словари,** которые никак не обойдешь.

Comment: Иногда, любители словесности, подобно любителям математики, реализуют себя в составлении задач,  основанных на парадоксах, на исключениях из правил, на противоречиях и трудностях их толкования. 
По моему, мы имеем дело с одной из задач подобного рода. В нашем случае, составитель задачи стремился сократить до минимума отрывок текста, общий смысл которого позволяет уточнить значение и определить наверняка, к какой части речи следует отнести слово (в составе текста) обладающее признаками и прилагательного, и причастия.

Comment: Никто не отрицает значимость справочников и словарей, но без предварительного анализа контекста задания можно просто открыть их не на той странице.

Comment: Я привела пример разбора слова "палящий" по словарю, там это прилагательное. Тот же подход не выявляет признаков прилагательного в слове "шокирующий". А словарь это закон. Откройте на нужной странице и докажите свою точку зрения. Ваши рассуждения меня не убедили. Грамматический анализ не подтверждает переход. Поэтому я считаю, что с вашей подачи в Сеть пошла неверная информация о статусе слова. Автор вопроса в принципе принимает ответы, которые подтверждают ее мнение. Вся эта история пока выглядит очень некрасиво и непрофессионально.

Comment: В данном случае, как мне думается, нет любителей словесности, но есть ученик, который не слушает учителя и старается доказать, что тот неправ и придирается. Об этом было сказано в самом первом вопросе этого автора, когда наши участники сочли, что Тихонов не прав, учитель не прав, а прав именно ученик. С того и начали, что завалили словарь.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/О-корне-в-слове-наставник

Comment: Там и наш @Ajgy, фигурирует со своими теориями (Тихонова нельзя изучать в школе), который сейчас исчез в срочном порядке неизвестно куда.

Comment: Если сначала рассматриваем контекст, а потом уже заглядываем в справочник, то можем  обнаружить, что "палящий" - это причастие (только похожее на прилагательное). Только один пример: " Угаси огнь, палящий страну новогородскую; удержи меч, лиющий кровь ее жителей!» Иоанн взял с собою из Москвы одного ученого в летописях дьяка, именем Стефана Бородатого, коему..."
 [Н. М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 6 (1811-1818)]

Comment: Слово палящий ПО СЛОВАРЮ может быть как причастием, так и прилагательным, но слово шокирующий ПО СЛОВАРЮ может быть только причастием.

Comment: Думаю, что соедующий пример опровергает Ваше утверждение о единственно возможной роли слова "шокирующий".    Однажды мне пришлось наблюдать редкостный, зримый, шокирующий переход от осени к зиме.
 [В. В. Ершов. Дневник (1992) // Летные дневники. 1984-2002 годы / Проза.ru]

Comment: Не вижу опровержения, не надо стараться примерами обойти СЛОВАРЬ. Здесь нет постоянного признака, это признак по действию: шокирует в данный момент. Ваш однородный ряд ничего не изменит.  То же самое могу посоветовать ученику, который занимается тем же самым. Старается быть умнее СЛОВАРЯ.  Лингвистам виднее!